# 2016 Nissan Altima Making Noise While Cold When Reversing

Tags: nissan, cold-start, altima

I will try to describe this as best as I can....My 2016 Nissan Altima is making a king of squeaky clacking noise while reversing and idle, but only when the engine is cold. The sound seems to come from the passenger side glove box area or somewhere in that direction. Any ideas on what could be causing it? Thank you!

Comment: So the sound stops immediately when you put the transmission in Drive?

Comment: Mostly, it still sounds a little creaky for a while but once car is hot it doesn't make noise. It only does it when in reverse or idle not drive.

Comment: An update....I went to lunch and tried to listen as much as possible. Sound is worse when parked, stopped holding the break, and reversing. It seems to stop when accelerating. Although, I guess I may not hear it because the acceleration and road sounds might drown it out. I hear it if I let go of the gas and let it roll. It's much louder inside the car, I can barely hear it standing outside of the car. Kind of reminds me of how a squeaky belt sounds but it isn't a continuous squeak like I've heard belts in the past. Also similar to squeaky suspension sound.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, because this answer does not completely agree with what you are saying about the sound.

I think you should remove the serpentine belt and check the entire length of it for cracks and missing chunks of rubber. After the belt is off, you should check the tensioner for adequate tension and for its bearing being intact with smooth rotation, no play and no gritty feel as you rotate it. Same with the idler or idlers: check their bearings.

For any pulley or wheel that is driven by the serpentine belt, if you can turn it by hand, check it for looseness, wobble or wiggle.

If you are not familiar with removing and reinstalling a serpentine belt, there are videos that show you how to do it, or you can take it to a mechanic.

Before anything, make a drawing of the path of the belt around all the pulleys and wheels, or you'll never get it back on right.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: It wasn't that.